# app.config custom section reading

Tags: .net, app-config

I have a problem reading custom section from app config.
I have

app.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="StartupFolders" type="Test.FolderConfiguration, Test"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <applicationSettings>
    <StartupFolders>
      <Folders>
        <Folder folderType="A" path="c:\foo" />
        <Folder folderType="B" path="C:\foo1" />
      </Folders>
    </StartupFolders>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

FolderConfiguration.cs:

```
namespace Test
{
    public class FolderElement : ConfigurationElement
    {

        [ConfigurationProperty("folderType", DefaultValue = "", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
        public string FolderType
        {
            get { return ((string)(base["folderType"])); }
            set { base["folderType"] = value; }
        }

        [ConfigurationProperty("path", DefaultValue = "", IsKey = false, IsRequired = false)]
        public string Path
        {
            get { return ((string)(base["path"])); }
            set { base["path"] = value; }
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(FolderElement))]
    public class FoldersCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
    {
        protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
        {
            return new FolderElement();
        }

        protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
        {
            return ((FolderElement)(element)).FolderType;
        }

        public FolderElement this[int idx]
        {
            get { return (FolderElement)BaseGet(idx); }
        }
    }
    class FolderConfiguration : ConfigurationSection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("Folders")]
        public FoldersCollection FolderItems
        {
            get { return ((FoldersCollection)(base["Folders"])); }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally in MainWindow.cs I use it all like:

```
 Configuration cfg = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            FolderConfiguration section = (FolderConfiguration)cfg.Sections["StartupFolders"];
```

it returns me *section == null*. I can;t understand what I'm doing wrong. Any help please

Answer (score 0):

```
class FolderConfiguration : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("Folders")]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(FoldersCollection), AddItemName = "Folder"]
    public FoldersCollection Folders
    {
        get { return ((FoldersCollection)(base["Folders"])); }
    }
}
```

also, on your FolderElements properties, you have:

```
get { return ((string)(base["folderType"])); }
set { base["folderType"] = value; }
```

should it be:

```
get { return ((string)(this["folderType"])); }
set { this["folderType"] = value; }
```

Does this help any?

**EDIT**

I'm basing my answer off [this](http://blog.danskingdom.com/adding-and-accessing-custom-sections-in-your-c-app-config/)

Does this return anything?
    var folderConfig = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("StartupFolders") as FolderConfiguration;
    if( folderConfig != null) { //loop through the collection }

Comment: There are no exceptions or extraordinary output. Program works normally. Just folderConfig  == null. At first glance I have pretty much the same as on the page above

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878374/how-to-read-multiple-values-in-c-sharp-app-config-file). It has only one level (in referenced question it's Users) but I don't see a reason for StartupFolders->Folders->Folder. You could then have only

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="Folders" type="ConsoleApplication1.FoldersConfigMapSection, ConsoleApplication1"/>
    </configSections>
    <Folders>
        <Folder folderType="A" path="c:\foo" />
        <Folder folderType="B" path="C:\foo1" />
    </Folders>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```